# Security feedback sought on Perl code running command on unsafe filename in Unix env

Tags: security, perl, unix

I'm looking for security feedback on the following fully functional code.

The code is trying to *safely* use the Unix 'file' command to give details about the file.

A hard link is used to create a safe filename that can be used in a command line.

The paramref is a hash read from config, and considered safe. `file_base_dir` is a directory with only alphanumerics in the name. The 'file' command is the standard one.

What ways could my code be exploited?

```
sub file_details {
    my ( $self, %arg ) = @_;
    my $filename = $arg{'filename'};
    my $paramref = $arg{'paramref'};
    my $file_cmd = '/usr/bin/file';

    my $safe_filename = $$paramref{'file_base_dir'} . "/link_to_unsafe_file_file_type_build";

    # Just in case the link exists.
    unlink($safe_filename);
    if ( not link( $filename, $safe_filename ) ) {
        confess "Failed to create link $safe_filename to $filename because $!";
    }

    my $file_type = `$file_cmd '$safe_filename'`;

    # remove the link
    unlink($safe_filename);
    $file_type =~ s/\A[^:]+://x;
    chomp $file_type;

    return $file_type;
} ## end sub file_details
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting approach with `link`.
If the only vulnerable parameter is `filename`,
this technique protects from malicious input,
because the `filename` parameter will not be part of the `` `...` `` bit executing shell commands.
I don't think it's possible to trick `link` into command execution.

On the other hand, although you say that *"file_base_dir is a directory with only alphanumerics in the name"*,
this function doesn't ensure that, simply trusts it to be true.
It would be good to add a call in this function to another function that validates the directory parameter.

I tried to think of other ways to validate the `filename` parameter,
without creating a link.
You could forbid certain characters such as `;` and `$` to prevent command injection,
but I'm not sure that's an exhaustive list.
So while the `link` trick seems hackish,
it does give comfort that vulnerable parameters never participate in a `` `...` `` shell expansion.

Comment: Also backticks might be able to be used to exploit the shell.  Yes link is hackish, but it seemed to give good protection.

Answer (score 1):

Safely quoting a filename is as simple as replacing all single quotes with `'\''`.

- Close single quoted string.
- Escaped single quote.
- Open new single quoted string.

That prevents the shell from interpreting *any* characters from the filename itself and preserves the original filename.

An additional alternative would be to hand `file` `/dev/stdin` or `-` as argument and then manually pipe the file to the processes standard input.

Comment: Yes, piping standard in does work. I got it to work that way as well. I used pipes, fork and exec.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just ensure there are no `..` in the path name and remove the whole symbolic link stuff. I'm not sure how that should improve security. The single quotes alone should make the parameter static.

Comment: The hard link stuff ensures a clean filename on the command line.  Imagine damage to the system if the insecure passed in filename was '; rm -fr / '   - including the single quotes.

Comment: @nslntmnx That's the magic behind quotes. `echo "$param"` will expand the environment variable, while `echo '$param'` will just print `$param` without expanding anything - no matter what's inside the quotes. All you have to do is to ensure that your file name doesn't include any unescaped `'` character, but that's something you'll have to check either way. In your case the unsafe filename might include `..` to escape your base directory and the hard/symbolic link won't help you to avoid that.

Comment: Regarding escaping with .., I just ensure there are no directory separators / in the $filename, then no number of .. will allow escape.